# Opposite of subsequent (non-chronological/logical)

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms

Just wondering, there is [a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43747/subsequent-consequent-presequent) regarding the *subsequent* in the context of logic (which can also be used in the context of chronology), but what if we're talking about an abstract sequence. For example it is possible to say:

> Subsequent files, however, can not be parsed.

But how would you say the opposite:

> The files which came earlier in sequence than the file in question, however, could not be parsed.

As far as I am aware

> Antecedent *(or precedent)* files, however, can not be parsed.

is invalid english (though I might be mistaken).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Preceding' is the opposite of subsequent

Comment: And also *anteceding*, but *preceding* would be much more common.

Comment: Preceding was the word I was looking for :D (Feeling soooooooo stupid now O:) )